# How to use cache on controller/service in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cache

I'm trying to add caching on my spring-boot app by following instruction on https://www.java4s.com/spring-boot-tutorials/how-to-configure-cache-in-spring-boot-applications/, but it doesn't work. I'm not entirely sure how to test it. I have a system.out.print under controller like in this article. If cache works then it will print "test" only once but return the same result from the request with same input. I have my code as below:

CurrencyController.java

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Cacheable(value="currency")
    public ResponseEntity getExchangedCurrency(final @RequestBody CurrencyExchange currencyExchange) {
        System.out.println("Test");
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
              .headers(responseHeaders)
              .body(currencyService.calculate(currencyExchange));
    }
```

App.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);



    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The way `@Cacheable` annotation works is utilizing  method parameter as key by default for the caching map. In this case `currencyExchange` object. Since it's object on each request spring request dispatcher creates new object and cache manager keeps as separate key.

> Req1 -> object1 -> map.put(object1, response)
>
> Req2 -> object2 -> map.contains(object2) -> false -> map.put(object2,
>   response)

If you think for all the post request send the same response from cache which doesn't the case always, you can change the key like this.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Cacheable(value="currency", key="#root.method")
public ResponseEntity getExchangedCurrency(final @RequestBody CurrencyExchange currencyExchange) {
    System.out.println("Test");
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
          .headers(responseHeaders)
          .body(currencyService.calculate(currencyExchange));
}
```

You can also use Spring Expression Language (SpEL) expression for defining key, if your currencyExchange has method `getId()` which can be used as potential cache key you can do like this

```
@Cacheable(value="currency", key="#root.args[0].getId()")
```

To clear cache Add `@EnableCaching` on spring boot main class, fixedDelay in milliseconds

```
@CacheEvict(allEntries = true, value = {"currency"})
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000 ,  initialDelay = 5000)
public void clearCache() {
    System.out.println("Cache cleared");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In CurrencyExchange there are 3 attributes: source, target and value. Is it possible to have the key that combine all these 3 values? I used this expression and it works but i'm not sure if this is the correct way.
`@Cacheable(value="currency", key="#root.args[0].getSource() + #root.args[0].getTarget() + #root.args[0].getValue()")` . Another question is how can I make the cache expired in specified amount of time? @Pasupathi Rajamanickam

Comment: @ChandaraChea yes you can implement your key like you said, to clear cache, updated answer.

Comment: I am skeptical if the RequestMapping method would directly be cached. The reason is because Spring Cache works on the principle of building a Singleton Object of a Proxy class built on top of the current class having the @Caheable annotation. At runtime, I doubt if Spring would be able to invoke the Singleton Cache. Rather it may be creating an instance of your controller thereby skipping the cache. I think instead of caching RequestMapping methods, you should build cache on a separate method & invoke. Keep us posted on what you find.

Comment: @SriniM you're right, if we are using `ehCache` spring-cache does work fine doing `@Cacheable` on `@RequestMapping`